# sending variable to javascript when img link clicked in jade

Tags: javascript, image, href, pug

I am taking addresses for images from an array, and going through the array to display each picture. I am wondering is there a way I can pass a unique variable associated with the img when it's clicked? I've tried to use a hidden input field with the variable in the value field, using req.body.email to access it, but this only returns the last value reached. Is there an img attribute I can use which can be accessed from the javascript file, and how would I access it?

EDIT: Code Add

```
    #results
     - for (var i=0, len = arraysArray.length; i<len; i++)
      - email = arraysArray[i][0]
      - pic = './' + email + '.jpg'
      - fname = arraysArray[i][1]
      - sname = arraysArray[i][2]
      - name = fname + ' ' + sname
      - county = arraysArray[i][3]
      - body = arraysArray[i][4]
      .picture
       a(href='/connection')
        img(src='#{pic}', height='80', width='80')
    #searchDetails
      #name
       h2#nameheading #{name}, County: #{county}, College: #{body}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`element.setAttribute(attribute,value)` to accomplish this. You could use attributes such as VALUE, NAME, or ID to store the value you want to pass.

Comment: I've tried to use that, but I might be doing it wrong, as it doesn't work. I've added my code above. I need to send the email for the picture that is being clicked in order to display their details, as the connect.js file is using the user's email to get all of their information.